# Multiple column scroll with fixed header and footer

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll, grid

I have an application that use grid layout and I try to add a new features to scoll multiple column at the same time. You can see what I did at the end.

So the aim of this is to be able to scroll the three columns at the same time, but fixed header and footer. The scroll can start on each column, that's why every column has the class named `scrollable-y`, and catch the event by doing `$(".scrollable-y").on('scroll', callback)`

But the problem with that is the scroll is very slow (scroll 1px by 1px) on Google Chrome. Also if you grab the item in the scrollbar, it's work fine... the problem is only when you scroll with the middle button of the mouse. Why?

Someone can help me please?

PS : It's just a part of my entire grid layout, so I can't change the structure...

[JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/hb7uxpga/49/)

That is what I did :

```js
$(".scrollable-y").on('scroll', function(e) {
    var ele = $(e.currentTarget);
    var top = ele.scrollTop();
    $('.scrollable-y').scrollTop(top);
});
```

```css
.container{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 200px 200px 200px;
  grid-template-rows:50px 150px 50px;
}

.scrollable-y{
  overflow: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.header{
  background: #ACACAC;
}

.footer{
  background: #DEDEDE;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">
    Tab 1
  </div>
  <div class="header">
    Tab 2
  </div>
  <div class="header">
    Tab 3
  </div>
  
  <div class="scrollable-y" id="scrollable1">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean sed elit quis dolor ultricies porta. Suspendisse tempus malesuada ipsum, et luctus mi dictum at. Aenean at accumsan eros. Phasellus dignissim mauris interdum felis dictum congue. Proin feugiat sodales pulvinar. Maecenas eu venenatis turpis. Vivamus id semper enim. Pellentesque a suscipit metus. Praesent pretium sem ut interdum luctus. Quisque ornare vitae est id pretium. Quisque cursus odio sit amet ante feugiat, quis ornare elit semper. Donec id ipsum quis sapien scelerisque laoreet vel sit amet elit. Donec lorem orci, iaculis non sodales vel, vehicula at eros. Quisque nec vulputate arcu.
  </div>
  <div class="scrollable-y" id="scrollable2">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean sed elit quis dolor ultricies porta. Suspendisse tempus malesuada ipsum, et luctus mi dictum at. Aenean at accumsan eros. Phasellus dignissim mauris interdum felis dictum congue. Proin feugiat sodales pulvinar. Maecenas eu venenatis turpis. Vivamus id semper enim. Pellentesque a suscipit metus. Praesent pretium sem ut interdum luctus. Quisque ornare vitae est id pretium. Quisque cursus odio sit amet ante feugiat, quis ornare elit semper. Donec id ipsum quis sapien scelerisque laoreet vel sit amet elit. Donec lorem orci, iaculis non sodales vel, vehicula at eros. Quisque nec vulputate arcu.
  </div>
  <div class="scrollable-y" id="scrollable3">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean sed elit quis dolor ultricies porta. Suspendisse tempus malesuada ipsum, et luctus mi dictum at. Aenean at accumsan eros. Phasellus dignissim mauris interdum felis dictum congue. Proin feugiat sodales pulvinar. Maecenas eu venenatis turpis. Vivamus id semper enim. Pellentesque a suscipit metus. Praesent pretium sem ut interdum luctus. Quisque ornare vitae est id pretium. Quisque cursus odio sit amet ante feugiat, quis ornare elit semper. Donec id ipsum quis sapien scelerisque laoreet vel sit amet elit. Donec lorem orci, iaculis non sodales vel, vehicula at eros. Quisque nec vulputate arcu.
  </div>
  
  
  <div class="footer">
    Footer 1
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    Footer 2
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    Footer 3
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I would try to trigger the scroll event only, if the mouse is over the according div. Right now it seems that you always trigger multiple scroll events.

Comment: Just try that : https://jsfiddle.net/hb7uxpga/58/ but it's the same. That's what you suggest?

Comment: Your code does not what I suggested, even if your intention was to do it ;) You see it in the console. Try to bind and unbind (on and off) the scroll event depending on the mousover. Maybe mouseenter and mousleave would be even better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried it myself and it looks fine for me.
https://jsfiddle.net/hb7uxpga/88/

```
$(".scrollable-y").on('mouseenter', function() {
    $(this).on('scroll', function() {
        $('.scrollable-y').scrollTop($(this).scrollTop());
    });
}).on('mouseleave', function() {
    $(this).off('scroll');
});
```